# My Observer is not executing

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, event-observer, place-order

Hi i'm new at magento 2 and i've been trying to create a Observer for checkout_submit_all_after and looks like that the Observer is not even called.

events.xml

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
       <observer name="place_order" instance="SussexDev\Extrato\Observers\Observers\PlaceOrder"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SussexDev_Observers" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="SussexDev_Extrato"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

PlaceOrder.php

```
    <?php
namespace SussexDev\Extrato\Observers\Observers;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class PlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /*
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getId();

        $sql = "update teste_order set order_id =".$orderId.";";
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $connection->query($sql);
        */
        $txt = "\n aaaaaa ";

        $this->_logger->log('DEBUG', $txt);
        $this->logger->info('Observer Atingido2', $observer->debug());

    }
}
```

registration.php

```
    <?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'SussexDev_Observers', __DIR__);
```

I want to Observer the event that happens when this button (Place Order) get click.
[image: button]

[image: files]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Module Step by step.

> **File**:-app/code/SussexDev/Observers/registration.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'SussexDev_Observers',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **File**:- app/code/SussexDev/Observers/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SussexDev_Observers" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> **File**:-app/code/SussexDev/Observers/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="place_order" instance="SussexDev\Observers\Observer\NewOrder"/>
    </event>

</config>
```

> **File**:-app/code/SussexDev/Observers/Observer/NewOrder.php

```php
<?php
namespace SussexDev\Observers\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class NewOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $txt = "\n aaaaaa ";
        $this->logger->log('DEBUG', $txt);
    }
}
```

Your module is completely created wrong. Please check below link how to create the module in Magento 2

https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/

Check the above files with code. create one by one and then hit below commands

> Run CLI Commands

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
```

I hope this will help you..!

Answer (score 1):

As per your image of directory structure you have created events.xml on adminhtml. Please create event.xml on frontend or global area. So it would call once user place order.