# Send checkout link after order placed by Magento Backend

Tags: magento2

I'm using Magento 2.3.5 for B2B sales.
My "Sales Man" needs to create an order using Magento backend (admin panel) and after que creation of the order, get a link of checkout to send to the customer.
So the customer will enter on checkout link and just make the payment.

How can i do that ?

Is possible to create a module for this ?  Or are there any extesion available on market for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use an Observer to observer the place order event? Check the answer of this one, it teachs how to create an observer. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313953/my-observer-is-not-executing

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little inexperienced with Magento programming.   Is there any example of the code exactly for the function that i need ?  Or do you know someone that i can hire for do it ?

Comment: check the link that i send, it teachs to create an Observer step by step and it is the same event(Creation of the order) that you are looking for. The Observers "watchs" when the one event is used. So this Observer will watch the place order event, and when this events got executed the observer execute the functions you'll program.

Comment: That part i understood.  The problem is:  the event "Creation of the order" will catch the orders created by backend ?   And the main problem is: How to execute the function to catch the chekout link for a determined order with everything configured, just missing to make the payment.

Comment: The "place order" event catch the events created by the click of that button. One event by one, so you will got everything that involves the order. About the checkout link i don't know, maybe the observer catch too. But the observer is fundamental to catch everything about the order. It's all my knowledge about magento, i'm new too, 1 month of experience. Maybe if you post prints of each situation someone can help more.